# T-SQL - trim leading characters

Tags: t-sql, texttrimming

I have a column (`nvarchar(255)`) and I'm looking to trim, to just display the name

Input

```
22;#Simon Smith
103;#John Doe
34;#Sarah Jones
1;#Robert Snow
...
```

Output Required

```
Simon Smith
John Doe
Sarah Jones
Robert Snow
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `;#` is always present, this should do the trick:

```
select substring('22;#Simon Smith', charindex(';#', '22;#Simon Smith')+2, 255)
```

---

Now you'll need to update your table:

update tablename
set columnname = substring(columnname, charindex(';#', columnname)+2, 255)

Replace `tablename` and `columnname` with the right values.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
RIGHT(YOUR_COLUMN, LEN(YOUR_COLUMN) - CHARINDEX('#', YOUR_COLUMN)) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: This is a better solution than the `substring` one.